# how to keep azure event hub connection alive for receiving batch diagnostic using amqp

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-batch

We had enabled diagnostic feature on our batch account to stream events to event hub which we are capturing in our application to take action based on batch task states. However we are noticing that the connection gets closed automatically(probably because no events occurring over night) and hence we have to bounce back the server every once in a while to receive the events/messages back again.

We still rely on java 7 and here are the dependencies that we added for batch processing:

```java
       //azure dependency
        compile('com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:7.0.0')
        compile('com.microsoft.azure:azure-batch:5.0.1') {
            //do not get transitive dependency com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jw because spring security still rely on old version of it
            excludes group: 'com.nimbusds', module: 'nimbus-jose-jw'
        }
        compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8')
        compile('org.apache.qpid:qpid-amqp-1-0-common:0.32')
        compile('org.apache.qpid:qpid-amqp-1-0-client:0.32')
        compile('org.apache.qpid:qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms:0.32')
        compile('org.apache.qpid:qpid-jms-client:0.40.0')
        compile('org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:1.1.1')
        //end of azure dependency
```

And here is the code snipped that does the connection, actually we used the code example given here : http://theitjourney.blogspot.com/2015/12/sendreceive-messages-using-amqp-in-java.html since we couldn't find any working example for java 7 in azure doc itself.

```java
     /**
     * Set up connection to the service bus using AMQP mechanism.
     * NOTE: Messages received from the message bus are not guaranteed to follow order.
     * */
    MessageConsumer initiateConsumer(MessageListener messageListener, Integer partitionInx, BatchEventHubConfig batchEventHubConfig) {
        // set up JNDI context
        String queueName = "EventHub"
        String connectionFactoryName = "SBCFR"

        Hashtable<String, String> hashtable = new Hashtable<>()
        hashtable.put("connectionfactory.${connectionFactoryName}", batchEventHubConfig.getAMQPConnectionURI())
        hashtable.put("queue.${queueName}", "${batchEventHubConfig.name}/ConsumerGroups/${batchEventHubConfig.consumerGroup}/Partitions/${partitionInx}")
        hashtable.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory")
        Context context = new InitialContext(hashtable)

        ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup(connectionFactoryName)
        Destination queue = (Destination) context.lookup(queueName)
        Connection connection = factory.createConnection(batchEventHubConfig.sasPolicyName, batchEventHubConfig.sasPolicyKey)
        connection.setExceptionListener(new BatchExceptionListener())

        connection.start()
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
        MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue)
        messageConsumer.setMessageListener(messageListener)
        messageConsumer
    }
```

So is there a way to track if a connection was closed, and if so re-start the connection again?
Any information to further diagnose this issue will be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue, I had used "SBCFR" as connectionFactoryName, looking closely at the example in the link, I should have used "SBCF". Also I updated the lib "org.apache.qpid:qpid-jms-client" from version "0.40.0" to "0.41.0"

Also in the above code, I shouldn't have used AUTO_ACKNOWLEGDE because for the longest time I thought something was wrong because I was never receiving the events in my local setup. Turned out other machines were also connected to the same consumer group and had already ack'ed the message.